# Visual Studio code makes React code weird

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

When I click 'save' on a React .js file in VSCode, the code changes form from this, for example:

```
import React from 'react';
const withClass = (WrappedComponent, className) => {
  return props => (
    <div className={className}>
      <WrappedComponent {...props}/>
    </div>
  );
};

export default withClass;
```

to this:

```
import React from 'react';
const withClass = (WrappedComponent, className) => {
    return props => ( <
        div className = { className } >
        <
        WrappedComponent {...props }
        /> <
        /div>
    );
};

export default withClass;
```

Why?

Comment: Are you using prettier? What are your settings?

Comment: Try to use the extension `.jsx` and see if it somehow fixes it. It can be a prettier or file formatter misconfiguration issue.

Answer (score 0):

The reason was this extension: JS-CSS-HTML Formatter (by: lonefy)